# Smallest number of turns needed to flip $P$ pencils, $N$ per turn, until they all point opposite their starting direction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, puzzle, binary

Imagine you have P pencils all faced away from you and you can flip them N at a time. Anytime a pencil is flipped its direction changes 180 degrees. Every time you have flipped N pencils that is considered one turn. You may not flip the same pencil twice in one turn. The goal is to flip all the pencils so that if they all start away from you then when you are finished they all end up towards you. Also, you can assume whole number N and P, and that P is greater than or equal to N. If T is the numbers of turns, what is the smallest value of T given P and N. What would be some sort of algorithm for this. I know there probably isn't just one function as there are many different patterns I see in some of the data I got, but is there some group of functions or logic statements I can use to solve this problem in a way where I can just plug in numbers into a function if P and  fit certain requirements? Thanks!

Comment: If n <= p, then the same n pencils could be flipped again and again for infinitely many turns.  If p < n, then nobody can have a turn.

Comment: What is the goal of flipping the pencils? With no goal, the smallest value of $T$ is just 0.

Comment: Are you asking for the minimal $T$ (given $P$ and $N$) such that all pencils are flipped (odd number of times) and facing you?

Comment: You need $tn=pq$ where $q$ is an odd number. The lowest $t$ occurs, clearly, when the products equate to the [*least* common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $p$ and $n$; the puzzle requires that $\operatorname{lcm}(p,n)/p$ is odd. If $\operatorname{lcm}(p,n)/p$ is even, the task cannot be completed.

Comment: @Blue:  I think you can flip different pencils different numbers of times.  See my example for $P=14,N=4$ in a comment to my answer.  I flip $13$ of the pencils once and one of them three times for $T=4$ That avoids the LCM restriction

Comment: @RossMillikan: Ah. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

After $T$ turns you have done $TN$ total flips of pencils.  You need to have flipped each pencil an odd number of times.

If $P$ is odd and $N$ is even you will never get there because you need an odd number of total flips and get them an even number at a time.

If $P$ is odd and $N$ is odd you need $T$ to be odd as well.  The minimum $T$ will be the lowest odd number that is at least $\frac PN$.

If $P$ is even you need $TN$ to be even as well.  If $N$ is odd you need $T$ to be even, so the minimum $T$ will be the lowest even number that is at least $\frac PN$.  There is an exception that $2$ is only acceptable if $\frac PN$ is exactly $2$.  Otherwise you need $4$.  For example, if $P=12,N=9$ you would like to flip nine pencils once and three pencils three times, but you can't flip a pencil three times when $T=2$.

If $P$ and $N$ are both even there is no restriction on the parity of $T$, so you just need the lowest whole number at least $\frac PN$ except that you need $3$ unless $\frac PN$ is whole.

Comment: These seems to work for many numbers but it don't always line up with my data. For example, For 14 pencils and 4 flips per turn I got that it takes 5 turns while your algorithm predicts 4 turns.

Comment: I flip $13$ of them once each and one of them $3$ times.  That works for $4$ turns.

Comment: I noted there are problems for small $T$ and updated.

Comment: How does this work though? The problem states that a pencil can only be flipped one time in any given turn so you cant just flip the last pencil three times

Comment: As long as I have at least three turns, I can flip a pencil three times.  I choose it in three of the turns.  That is where the problem with $1$ or $2$ comes from.  For $P=14,N=4$ I flip $(1,2,3,4),(1,5,6,7),(1,8,9,10),(11,12,13,14)$

Comment: Ok this makes sense, thank you!